# Cycle (refresh) between multiple pages?

Tags: php, javascript, refresh

I have a set of pages with the following names....

- update1.php
- update2.php
- update3.php
- update4.php
- update5.php
- update6.php
- update7.php

At the moment, I have all 7 open on Chrome and refreshing every 30 minutes using the following code.

```
<body onload="setInterval('window.location.reload()', 1800000);">
```

I want to stick all these pages together so that I need only 1 page open. Is there a way to make a page refresh every 5 mins, but load a different section each time?

I was thinking of doing something like this, but it seems a bad way of doing it...

```
$refresh = $_GET['refresh'];

if (!isset($refresh)) { //update1 stuff; //reload page with &refresh=2 }
elseif ($refresh == 1) { //update1 stuff; //reload page with &refresh=2 }
elseif ($refresh == 2) { //update2 stuff; //reload page with &refresh=3 }    
elseif etc.....
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Setting `window.location` to a new URL will redirect you wherever you want. That page could then redirect you to the next one, etc.

Comment: why are you involving a browser in this at all?> sounds like something that should be running as a background task scheduled via cron

Comment: @Dagon I agree, but I have windows hosting, so I can't use CRON. If you know of a windows way of doing this, please let me know and I'll research how to do it. I do plan to move to a linux host sometime in the future to avoid all this hassle.

Comment: windows scheduler then.

Comment: @Dagon Do you mean windows scheduler on MY pc? Cos I have a mac... or can you do windows scheduler on a windows host? I use ixwebhosting... I'll ask them about it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon Actually that's the easiest way to do it and will work fine. I didn't even think of it.. doh. I think I'll try Aiias's method below because I'd like to put this all on one page also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php code that outputs the page html code, try something like this:

```
<?php echo ($_GET['refresh'] % 7) + 1; ?>.php // Name of next page

?refresh=<?php echo ($_GET['refresh'] % 7) + 1; ?>"; // Name of next page + 1

// All together
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = 'update<?php echo ($_GET['refresh'] % 7) + 1; ?>.php?refresh=<?php echo ($_GET['refresh'] % 7) + 1; ?>';}, 1800000);">
```

This will open the new page with an incremented number after the specified time interval. The [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) helps us run through the pages in a consistent loop.

References

- [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)
- [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: Wow thanks.. yeah this looks exactly like what I'm trying to do. I'll give it a try just now.

Comment: @Cully - Updated my answer to use single quotes around `window.location.href = ' ... '` since it's within the double quotes already of `onload = " ... "`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I have it working right now, but also I'm modifying it a little to put all the info on a single page. FYI, I had to remove the `( ) + 1` before the last ` % 7) + 1; ?>';}, 1800000);">` as it was counting the refresh up twice per refresh.

Comment: @Cully - No problem, happy to help. I have modified my answer to remove that extra `+ 1`. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can Put All Scripts in one page and can use

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800" />`  in `head`

to refersh browser every after `30 Minutes`

Comment: I can't load them all at once because they are opening hundreds of pages and will time out every time. This is why I need to load only a section at a time.